# Passing values from one class to main?

Tags: java, hashmap

so here is my question and my approach. In the Main class I have this code in order to parse the commandline input. It is passed to another class in order to handle the input.

My question is, how can I pass the values from the hashmap to the main method for further processing, but ONLY if the values are all entered correctly and nothing is missing (which should be caught by the exceptions)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
            CommandLineParser commandLineParser = new CommandLineParser(args);  
}
    }
```

And in another class I have the CommanLineParser

```
public class CommandLineParser {

public CommandLineParser(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> hash_map = new HashMap<>();
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main method already has the variables in your class scope, you can access them like this;

```
String s_mode = commandLineParser.getMode();
```

which will either be null, or will have the value you expected.

You *could* have a boolean value inside your class to define whether everything has happened in the way you wanted and return that first for ease, or instead of null checking everything.

**edit - But I would want to make a method like;

```
public boolean processArgs(String args))
```

after the class has been created, and return the success as part of the boolean method.

So would do;

```
CommandLineParser commandLineParser = new CommandLineParser();
boolean success = commandLineParser.process(args);

if (success)
{
    //get stuff
}
```

*** Is it only one set of results you need? As you could set the processor as a worker class, then model your objects properly, then have a list of your object where you could call those methods in each instance.

You'd also have to actually set them at some point in your method;

```
mode = hash_map.get("r");
```

instead of;

```
String mode = hash_map.get("r");
```

****edit
so your check at them moment for what you've asked for in the comments is;

```
if (!mode.equals("s") || mode.equals("sd") || mode.equals("v") || mode.equals("vd") || mode.equals("d"))
```

if mode is not "s" (! means not), but is sd or v or vd or d

You're saying you want;

```
String s_mode = hash_map.get("r");
if (s_mode.matches("s|sd|v|vd|d"))
{
    mode = s_mode; //or whatever you want to do with it
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however will s_mode be the value of "r" of my hashmap? Because as I understand the allocation of "String mode = hash_map.get("r")" is only locally, isn't it? However, I want to make sure that the variable mode which is accessible hold the value of r of the hashmap... And only if r has the value s, sd, v, vd or d.

Comment: yes unless you move the string initialization to the global scope, then they're accessible by your factory method

Comment: You mean when I put "private String mode;" on top of "public class CommandLineParser"? And your comment means I should leave it as it is?

Comment: no actually it looks ok, your strings are private, but the method to get them is public, so you should be able to get them with getMode() or getPath() or whatever

Comment: ah yeah, then also, you have to check this first "And only if r has the value s, sd, v, vd or d" and then set your variable if that is true right?